# when run "npm run test" in the docker file getting No captured browser, open <url>

Tags: angular, docker

I have using angular app with a docker file. I have created a docker file and see code below:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/raju/ang-sample

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","run","test"]
```

Later run the following commands

1. docker run -it 8a155f88c4c2
2. docker run -it 8a155f88c4c2

Getting the following output:

[image: output]

Please help me any one?

Comment: so, do you have any Chrome browser on your platform, and if so, have you tried setting `CHROME_BIN` environment variable to its name/path?

Comment: Don't know  docker inside chrome browser exist  or not

Comment: I am using windows 10 pc. I have chrome browser inside it